# How to call a function Multiple times

Tags: javascript

Here is the code snippets

```
let sum = a => b => b ? sum(a + b) : a;
console.log(sum(10)(20)(3)(4)());
```

So we are calling the sum function 5 times
But let's assume we have an array of any length which contains only numbers

```
let arrayValue = [1,2,3,4,5,...];
```

now I want to call the sum function to the length of that array where the last call should be () as it does not contain any number;

Desired Output should be `sum(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)()` and this will generate programmatically depending on the length of the array

Comment: *"So we are calling the sum function 5 times..."* No, you're calling `sum` **once**, then calling the function it returns once, then calling the function *that* returns once, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Make a simple function that returns the sum.

Comment: Yes, true @T.J.Crowder We are calling the Function sum once every time but the total number of times it calls is 5. So how can we manage that programmatically??

Comment: It's the requirement @Ram

Comment: @MuhammadTahir - No, that's incorrect. There are five calls being made, but not all of them are to `sum`. (Actually, I think there are at least six, since there's a call to `sum` buried in there.) Some of them are to the function `sum` returns, or to the function *that function* returns. (I was incorrect earlier to say there was only one call to `sum`, though; there will be at least two with what you've shown.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder right
Got that 
So any idea! How can do this programmatically? when we don't know the arguments and how many times we should execute

Comment: @MuhammadTahir The only way that I can think of for doing that is using `eval`. The requirement doesn't make much sense anyways. Funny thing is you still need to use a loop for generating the statement before evaluating it.

Comment: @Ram - No, there's no need for `eval` here.

Comment: I was talking about generating a statement like `sum(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)()` dynamically and evaluating it exactly like that.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at

```
console.log(sum(10)(20)(3)(4)());
```

It's basically doing this:

```
const x1 = sum(10);
const x2 = x1(20);
const x3 = x2(3);
const x4 = x3(4);
const x5 = x4();
console.log(x5);
```

So the question is: How do we do that from this starting point?

```
let arrayValue = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

The answer is either a loop or recursion. A loop is simple enough, so let's do that:

```
let x = sum;
for (const value of arrayValue) {
    x = x(value);
}
x = x();
console.log(x);
```

```js
let sum = a => b => b ? sum(a + b) : a;

function example(arrayValue) {
    let x = sum;
    for (const value of arrayValue) {
        x = x(value);
    }
    x = x();
    console.log(arrayValue.join(", "), "=>", x);
}

example([10, 20, 3, 4]);
example([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

We start by setting `x` to `sum` (the function, *not* a call to it), then for each array value we call whatever function `x` currently refers to passing in the value and storing the return value back in `x` again. When we run out of values, we call the result with no argument.

Answer (score -2):

You can loop over to the length of the array. You can use `.length` property to do this and then call your function inside the loop.

Example:

```js
let arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , …];

for (let i = 0; i < arrayValue.length; i++) {
  someFunction(arrayValue[i]);
}
```

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: ```
let sum = a => b => b ? sum(a + b) : a;
console.log(sum(10)(20)(3)(4)());
```

The result of this Statement is 37 We don't want to call the function to the number of times we are calling the function in recursive manner